# How to connect SonarQube 6.4 to SonarLint 3.5

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I'm trying to connect SonarLint to SonarQube but I have the following error `The following plugins do not meet the required minimum versions, please upgrade them on your SonarQube server:
  java (installed: 3.14, minimum: 4.0)`

SonarQube version : 6.4
SonarLint version : 3.5

How can i do resolve my problem ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube server uses several language specific scanner plugins for analysis like Java, PHP etc. SonarJava is the Java specific module of it.
The problem in your case is that the SonarJava version in your SonarQube server is 3.14, whereas SonarLint works with version 4.0 onwards. Latest version is 4.15.

You can verify this by accessing the SonarQube admin dashboard as seen below. By updating the SonarJava version your problem can be resolved.

[image: SonarQube Update Center]